# 'openssl/err.h': No such file or directory

Tags: pip, openssl, quic

I'm trying to use [aioquic](https://github.com/aiortc/aioquic) on Windows but I get this error on the initial `pip install -e .`:

```
src/aioquic/_crypto.c(4): fatal error C1083: Non Š possibile aprire il file inclusione: 'openssl/err.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.26.28801\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I installed openssl via Chocolatey, but that file seems to be missing. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same error!

Answer (score 1):

To use aioquic on Windows you need to set a couple of Environment variables.

Namely `$Env:INCLUDE` and `$Env:LIB` are needed to point to the directory where OpenSSL header files and libraries are located, if not you'll get the `'openssl/err.h': No such file or directory` error as you have discovered.

To fix, open a command prompt as an admin and do...

`setx INCLUDE "C:\Progra~1\OpenSSL\include" /M`

and

`setx LIB "C:\Progra~1\OpenSSL\lib" /M`

To note, the `/M` flag here just specifies that the variables should be set in the system wide `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` rather than `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.

Close the prompt, then open another and then try again with...

`pip install -e .`

See https://github.com/aiortc/aioquic